# rsync from two servers to a common location

Tags: linux, rsync

I have two servers and I want to `rsync` files from both servers to a single location.

- Server 1 has files A and B
- Server 2 has files A and B
- After `rsync` server 3 has file A and B

When a user deletes file A from server 1 and file B from server2, server 3 shouldn’t have any files on it.

But its not working properly in my setup:

- `rsync --delete server1 server3`
- `rsync --delete server2 server3`

It deletes A first and B second but A will be copied again from server 2. Instead of getting empty directory I end up again with A.

Does anyone  have a work around to this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that as you think. If you delete file A from server1, it still exists on server2 and will be copied to server3 from there. Same goes for file B. If you delete it from server2, it still exists on server1 and will be copied from there. You could maybe first rsync server1 and server2 to delete files on each that have been deleted on the other. And then sync to server3, if that is applicable in your case.

Comment: in that case also (rsync between servers) file B will be copied over to server2 on the first rsync.  how can i server1 and server2 to delete each other

Comment: Well in that case you would need to monitor folder for changes, and on change rsync it to other server. I think this might be much easier if you used something similar to Dropbox (i.e. Owncloud?).

Answer (score 0):

The rsync command you're doing is making server3 a strict copy of whatever server it's copying from.  So it becomes a clone of server1 (with A missing and B there), then you tell it to be a clone of server2 (with A there and B missing)

Can you move back a level and explain what you're aiming to do here?

Comment: I have to take a master copy of two folders at different locations. if a file is deleted from location1 its not needed in location2 also and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
rsync -u --delete server1 server3
rsync --delete server2 server3
```

From rsync man page:

```
  -u, --update                update only (don’t overwrite newer files)
```

Whether it's server1 or server2 who does the sync first, it will respect if the file is already in server3.

Note however that you should put your rsync commands in 1 script and put a flag file to indicate that the sync will not run if the other is running.

Let me know if that helps.